# What options are there to find out if my ASP.NET MVC view is not XHTML compliant

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, tag-soup

**Clarification**: Thanks for the suggestions of tools for validating XHTML. I'm primarily looking for a solution that will run server side (or on the client with jQuery) so i can set it and forget it during development - and get told when I have issues without having to run a tool all the time.

---

All this [tag soup stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363465/how-do-i-get-over-my-fears-of-in-my-asp-net-mvc-markup) scares me with ASP.NET MVC !!

I'd be less scared if I could validate each and every view coming out of my view generator for XHTML compliance. This is especially important with the amount of jQuery I am planning on writing. i dont want to spend hours debugging something just to find out I had an unclosed tag somewhere that prevented a selector from working.

What options are there for this. Off the top of my head I'm looking for solutions like the following, but not sure which of these are practical:

- JQuery XHTML checker
- IIS filter
- Browser plugin (I assume theres something for Firebug plugin to do this)
- Doing something clever with the MVC View classes (I'm not sure if this is possible or worthwhile persuing).
- Modifying the HTML writer to check on 'flush()' and throw an exception if the output is not XHTML.
- ASP.NET configuration option I'm not aware of to validate the page.

All options welcome answers !

I'd prefer a server side technology so during debugging I can throw a hard exception, and in production I can log any errors. It must validate the full page after the master page has been applied. Looking for warnings in the IDE is not a good enough solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a plugin there's [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249) for Firefox.

Comment: i just installed this. the XHTML state of the document seems a little buried in all the miscellaneous HTML errors, but ill play with it some more. while i care about HTML compliance somewhat I care less if i'm missing a 'type' tag than if my document isnt symantically correct in its most basic form

Answer (score 0):

[w3c html validator](http://validator.w3.org/source/) is avalable as source so you can download it and do prety much anything you want with it. You could set it up with a list of URLs to constantly crawl your test server and log any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said, the W3C validator is out there, but on a side note to check for the accessibility of your views/ site you can you [TAW](http://www.tawdis.net/taw3/cms/en).

I realise this is slightly off topic, but it's still in an important part of web-site development.